# Comparator - Sorting a List of Objects without using Collections

Tags: java, sorting

Suppose we are living in a class named **Person** with instance variables `name` and `age`.

I would like to know whether it is possible to write a method that

- sorts a list ascendingly with respect to *name* (lexicographical order) and *age*,
- does not use **Collections**,
- does use **Comparator**.

If I were to use **Collections**, my code would be as follows:

```
 public static void sortPeople(List<Person> people){
    Collections.sort(people,new Comparator<Person>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2){

         if (p1.name.compareTo(p2.name)<0){
             return -1;
        } else if (p1.name.compareTo(p2.name)>0){
            return 1; 
        } else {
          return p1.age-p2.age;
        }
        }}); 
 }
```

But as I said, I would like to know if it is possible to do it differently.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: *"I would like to know whether it is possible to write a method that..."* - Yes

Comment: Yes, it is possible by applying any of the well-known sorting algorithms (and, of course, for example, using some old-fashion loop/s).

Comment: See the Java 8 Stream approach answer on the duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments!